# preparedStatement.setString(1,"null"), is being interpreted as null instead of a string (after preparedStatement.addBatch())

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, netezza

PreparedStatement setString is taking a "null" (as if `String a = "null"`) and after .addBatch its being transformed into a normal null (as if `String a = null` ).

I dont know how to be able to bypass this misinterpretation since a lot of lines are being executed at once after they have been all added as batch ...  (the sql statement is an `INSERT INTO` ...) (the VarChar cannot be null but `String a = "null"` can be accepted by the table if its sent without batch ... the whole program stops due to the error msg from the server)

Error Message : 
Error while writing data into database... org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR:  Column 17 : Field cannot contain null values

Code :

```
preparedStatement.setString(17, x); //currently x was recieved as "null"
preparedStatement.addBatch() //after other parameters were filled then this statement
preparedStatement.executeBatch(); //after the logs this statement is executed.
```

Hopefully theres a quick fix for that

I used this bypass but thought there could be a better one ... (since i cannot change the databases default value or manipulate the data ... )

```
if(helper.toLowerCase().equals("null"))
    helper = (helper.equals("null") ? "null ":"NULL ");

preparedStatement.setString(17, helper);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Keep in mind that I never used Netezza and I am not able to try anything. This is a collection of information found in the official documentation of IBM Netezza.*

If I am reading this right, there is an explicit conversion of text value "null" to recognize the absence of a value... for [external table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_external_tables.html). The reason is simple, an external table is a flat file so it probably store everything as TEXT without separator, but with delimited size file.

[Handle the absence of a value](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_handle_absence_value.html)

> In SQL, a record must include a value if a column is declared as not null. When a record contains no value for a column, the column is considered to be null. The system provides an explicit and implicit method for conveying nullness.
>   -  The explicit method includes a specific token in the field instead of a value. **By default, this token is the word “null” (not case-sensitive)**. **You can use the nullValue option to change this token to any other 1 - 4 character alphabetic token**. You can precede or follow an occurrence of the explicit null token in a non-string field with adjacent spaces. For the system to recognize an explicit null token in a string field, the token cannot have preceding or trailing adjacent spaces. The explicit null token method **makes it impossible to express a string that consists of exactly the text of the null token.**

Then, we can see the same idea in [The NullValue option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/r_load_nullvalue.html)

> Specifies the string to use for the null value, with a maximum 4-byte UTF-8 string. The default is ‘NULL’.

You could replace this option for this table with any other `String` but I believe this would just move the problem...

So my solution, set the `NullValue` for your table to `" "` (a space) and in your project trim every value, you would never be able to have a `" "` since it would be trimmed as `""`.

Comment: i have used a space after the null to bypass this problem ("null "/"NULL ")... i didnt know its a limitation by netezza ... is there any nicer way to be able to solve this issue ?

Comment: I have edited this with the information on `NullValue` option. This might be on the table itself, hard to tell for me..

Comment: @Xero, I would gladly appreciate if you can confirm how to set the option. This could be usefull to add for future people passing here ;)

Comment: i cannot change the representation of the NullValue due to it being a huge Database and must be contained as such ... i will check if i could solve this issue without the bypass i made with this code  : if(helper.toLowerCase().equals("null"))
    {
      helper = (helper.equals("null") ? "null ":"NULL ");
    }

Comment: best part is if addBatch isnt used then the string null is taken correctly XD

Comment: @xero It would be nice to be able to host a dev version to play with it. It could be the driver that is buggy or because the batch use an external table to store the value temporary. But an IBM product with a demo version ... I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Given your question I think you're trying to insert String `null` unless specified otherwise.
Simplest solution to this problem would be to have column's default value as string `null` so you would not have to worry about specifying it in your code that may or may not interpret it as empty.
i.e adding constraint over column definition `NOT NULL DEFAULT 'null'`

Comment: @AxelH He's not suggesting getting rid of the NOT NULL constraint, rather he's suggesting the column definition be changed to `NOT NULL DEFAULT 'null'`, so that if the column is omitted from the insert statement it will have the word `"null"` in it by default. Seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: @AlexH, in my answer I have mentioned about **adding** DEFAULT constraint not removing it.

Comment: @JonK didn't read it like that!! `"null"` is already the value provided so it might not work but it could !

Comment: @AxelH to overcome _problems_ by using "null" in `preparedStatment` - why don't we just not use it and let database take care of it. ;)